# What is the meaning of z_order in OSM/pgsql datamodel?

Tags: osm2pgsql

Site http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql/schema describe OSM/pgsql database schema. But I don't understand the meaning of z_order in this model.

Comment: Simply the order that things are drawn, just like in CSS really.

Comment: Thank you! Any Link or Example?

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#Import_style I don't have an example, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z_order is a field in osm2pgsql datamodel that map OSM Layers in OSM tags to a number in osm2pgsql model.

Links:

[Osm2pgsql tables](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:HowTo_minutely_hstore#Tabellenstruktur)

[OpenStreetMap Layer](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Layer#Within_the_renderer_.2F_Mapnik)

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap data does not include z_order as a tag. The z_order artificial tag is computed by using logical rules when OSM data is prepared for rendering. How osm2pgsql program does this is explained in https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql

> z_order Adds a column that is used for ordering objects in the render.
>   It mostly applies to objects with highway=* or railway=*. Use with
>   int4 as the data type.

The tags and corresponding z_values are defined in the style file. See https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/932ded7f191bad5994b67ff60038ffe211d00efe/style.lua which is setting z_value to -10 for tunnels and to +10 for bridges

```
-- Array used to specify z_order per key/value combination.
-- Each element has the form {key, value, z_order, is_road}.
-- If is_road=1, the object will be added to planet_osm_roads.
zordering_tags = {{ 'railway', nil, 5, 1}, { 'boundary', 'administrative', 0, 1},
    { 'bridge', 'yes', 10, 0 }, { 'bridge', 'true', 10, 0 }, { 'bridge', 1, 10, 0 },
    { 'tunnel', 'yes', -10, 0}, { 'tunnel', 'true', -10, 0}, { 'tunnel', 1, -10, 0},
    { 'highway', 'minor', 3, 0}, { 'highway', 'road', 3, 0 }, { 'highway', 'unclassified', 3, 0 },
    { 'highway', 'residential', 3, 0 }, { 'highway', 'tertiary_link', 4, 0}, { 'highway', 'tertiary', 4, 0},
    { 'highway', 'secondary_link', 6, 1}, { 'highway', 'secondary', 6, 1},
    { 'highway', 'primary_link', 7, 1}, { 'highway', 'primary', 7, 1},
    { 'highway', 'trunk_link', 8, 1}, { 'highway', 'trunk', 8, 1},
{ 'highway', 'motorway_link', 9, 1}, { 'highway', 'motorway', 9, 1},
```